# User or Role Authorization Check

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a question about authorization.

Say i have an endpoint such as:
/users/{id}/password

say this is a post request and allows you to change a password for a specific user.

Is there a way to authorize/only allow this endpoint to be used by the user currently signed in or any user which has a specific role.
(This information is available in the claim of the access token)

Is this even right maybe might first question...

If it is, then I understand that there is both role-base and claim-based authorization, by they (from what I see) use specific values that they check against. So this would work with roles but not with the user id as this is dynamic and cant write all the ids to check against when creating the polocy for instance.

I need to check the user id of the request against the token user id to check if they are authorised to use the endpoint. If not then are they an admin? If they are then its ok they are not the target user, they can change it anyway.

Also I cant seem to find any examples of two different sets on authorisation being used in an either/or circumstance (e.g. like here it would be either you can use it if you the user it targets or an admin)

I currently solve this issue in my endpoint by fetching the identity and checking the claims manually.

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
var userDataClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.UserData).FirstOrDefault();
var roleClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).FirstOrDefault();

if(Convert.ToInt32(userDataClaim.Value) != id && roleClaim.Value != "1")
{
    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Is there not a better way to do this. I wouldn't want to mess all of my endpoint functions with this sort of checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this before your endpoint like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

Also for making the **Roles** check as optional, you have to inherit `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` class and also override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method and in this method you can add few checks of your own like you were going to add in each endpoint.

Comment: Yer so i understand you can use role based authorization. But can you use it optionally?
For instance if that false and the user is not an admin, it will fail and return an unauthorized.
I want that to be an optional check that the user needs to be either an admin OR have the same user id as the one they are targeting.

Comment: for that you can inherit System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute class and override HandleUnauthorizedRequest method and in this method you can add the role based checked as optional

Answer (score 1):

You will have to built your own custom authorize attribute .
It's pretty straight forward, and if you are only tweaking it to check against the currently logged in user , then you can use the same definition of the AuthorizeAttribute. 
Take a look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). (AuthorizeAttribute.cs)

```
protected virtual bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
            {
                throw Error.ArgumentNull("actionContext");
            }

            IPrincipal user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;
            if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 && !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (_rolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

If you want to verify against the claims you can modify the IsAuthorized and do it this way :

```
var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            if (!(principal.HasClaim(x => x.Type == ClaimType && x.Value == ClaimValue)))
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }

            //User is Authorized, complete execution
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if (userId = currentUser){
 get userInfo from whose access token
} 
else{
 get user admin info from database 
} 
i will suggest middleware for this. You need auth role and get userInfo i suggest build a new service for it.